# Permalink/Pagination issue: Category base name same as page name

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I currently have a page called "Blog" (slug "blog"), which loads a index.php. All posts in index.php belong to only one post category. A sidebar on index.php contains category links (via wp_list_categories) which load archive.php for that given taxonomy.

The problem I am running into is that I currently have the category base name set to the same slug as the page: "blog". I am aware that this can cause issues with the rewrite rules, but for the most part everything looks fine. The only issue is with pagination pages for index.php (mysite.com/blog/page/2 does not work while mysite.com/blog/foo-category/page/2 works fine).

Is there a rewrite rule that can help with my current situation? And if so some help would be appreciated.

If this is a bad idea, please speak up as well. I was hoping to achieve a somewhat RESTful url structure, but wordpresses permalink structure doesn't appear to be the most flexible.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is untested, but should work for you. Visit the permalinks settings page to flush rewrite rules after adding:

```
function wpa_fix_blog_pagination(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'blog/page/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=blog&paged=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_fix_blog_pagination' );
```

Comment: Thanks Milo, that worked perfectly. Since you seem to know a thing or two about rewrite rules, do you see anything wrong/dangerous about using this permalink structure down the road?

Comment: Can this be used with i18n for "blog" since I'm translating my custom taxonomy slug (via WPML otherwise)?