# Rewrite with pagination /foo/page/2/ to posts of a given category, page 2

Tags: php, categories, url-rewriting, pagination, rewrite-rules

This

```
add_action('init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^foo', 'index.php?category_name=category1', 'top');
});
```

works and allows `example.com/foo/` to display all the posts from `category1`.

But then the pagination doesn't work.

There is a link on the bottom of this page that shows "Older posts", and that redirects to `example.com/foo/page/2/`.

**Question: how to have `example.com/foo/page/2/` display all the posts from `category1`, page 2?**
(without a third party plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Solved with:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^foo/page/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?category_name=category1&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');    
add_rewrite_rule('^foo', 'index.php?category_name=category1', 'top');
```

The order between these two lines here is important.

See also [Permalink/Pagination issue: Category base name same as page name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114606/permalink-pagination-issue-category-base-name-same-as-page-name).